# Ordered occurrences of characters in string

Tags: haskell

I want to get all the occurrences of the characters I have in a string.
So for example if I have the string "nunddrdr" I want to get "nnudddrr".

This is how the code looks like which should achieve this:

```
usort :: String -> String

l :: String
l = ""

usort (x:xs)
    | xs == []  = l ++ [x]
    | otherwise = l ++ [n | n <- (x:xs), n = x] ++ usort (xs)
```

It doesn't work correctly because it also proccesses already used characters.

Comment: You should prefer pattern matching to an equivalent guard. In this case, `[x]` or `x:[]` to `| xs == []`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly observed that your recursive calls to `usort` are not removing the characters that have already been used, so you will need to modify the function so that it does this. You can use `filter` to select only the elements of the list that match some criteria, so we can remove the already used characters like so:

```
filter (\=x) xs
```

We can select all of the characters that match `x` in the same manner, by using

```
filter (==x) xs
```

You can use these two things to create your `usort` function:

```
usort (x:xs) = x : (filter (==x) xs) ++ usort (filter (/=x) xs)
```

However, you have failed to consider the case when you will be trying to sort an empty list, so you will also need to add:

```
usort [] = []
```

Putting this together, you get

```
usort::(Eq a)=>[a]->[a]
usort [] = []
usort (x:xs) = x : filter (==x) xs ++ usort (filter (/=x) xs)
```

Comment: Thank you! How could I do the same function with a String-List as an output. So like for every "block" ogf characters one string?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: ["nn", "u", "ddd", "rr"] following my example from above. The thing is that I should order those after certain properties (length, order in alphabet) and I guess this will be easier managed with a list.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. It is fairly easy to modify the current version to do that. Is there anything that you have tried so far? Hint: think about how you would generate just ["nn"] first, and then try and get the full list once you can do that.

Comment: Ok I got it. Just made brackets over the "x : filter (==x) xs" expression. I like the notation in one line. Until now I did everything in many line like before.

Comment: Yep, so you can use `usort (x:xs) = (x : filter (==x) xs) : usort (filter (/=x) xs)` to get your list. Make sure that you understand why. You will need to change the signature of the function to `usort :: (Eq a)=>[a]->[[a]]` as well, of course.

Comment: Sure. Any suggestions on how I could sort this list? Is there any function in Prelude which allows me sorting by length?

Comment: Have a look at the function `sortBy`, which is in `Data.List`.